# JSF: Invoke method on returned object of a method

Tags: java, jsf-2, el, method-call

I've stumbled upon a problem I don't seem to be able to solve on my own with my basic knowledge of jsf.

I have a session scoped object which is referenced by **userSession**.

So if I want to get the property **loginTimestamp** I just call **userSession.loginTimestamp** which is no problem and works perfectly fine.

Now I also have a method **getLoggedInUser** which gives me an Object of the type user.
On that object I can call a method **getNickname** which should give me a string.

The problem is that I want to call something like

```
<div id="login">
    <h:outputText value="Welcome #{userSession.getLoggedInUser.getNickname}" />
    <h:form id="logoutForm">
        <h:commandButton class="Submit" value="logout"
            action="#{Logout.logout}" />
    </h:form>
</div>
```

No the method getLoggedInUser has no property loggedInUser. But how do I just call that method within the value-attribute and call a method on that return type?

Maybe it is not even possible and I missed something crucial here. But wouldn't it be really annoying to always set a property for anything you want to use instead of being able of breaking it down this way?

Thanks already for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserSession

```
public String getLoggedUserNickname(){
   return getLoggedInUser().getNickname();
}
```

View

```
<h:outputText value="Welcome #{userSession.loggedUserNickname}" />
```

Or just

```
<h:outputText value="Welcome #{userSession.loggedInUser.nickname}" />
```

--

Whenever you call for property for example `myProp` like `userSession.myProp` it will look for `getMyProp()` function.  case-sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Lose the `get` prefixes. This should work:

```
<h:outputText value="Welcome #{userSession.loggedInUser.nickname}" />
```